# Doctrine entity validation at construct

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-validator

I'm trying to improve myself with doctrine, and doing best practices.
I found a good presentation of best practices : https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/50

I try to have a valid object after __construct.
(see https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/52)
But I'm using @Assert annotation for validating my object.

How can I do to validate ? Have to inject the validator service inside my object at __construct ?

My object :

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    public function __construct($email, ValidatorInterface $validator){

          $this->email = $email;
          $validator->validate($this); // good practice ?

    }
```

My final goal is to unit test the input validation of this entity.

Thank you

**Edit :**

Basing on the answer of Yonel, I added this in the end of my constructor :

```
 $errors = $validator->validate($this);
    if(count($errors) > 0) {
        $errorsString = (string) $errors;
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($errorsString);
    }
```

Is it a good practices or not ? If not, why ?
Thank you!

Comment: Check better the presentation: The named constructor accept a form object this mean that the form do him work (validate with the validator).

Comment: Nice answer, I see that now, Thank you !

Comment: Thanks Xero, let me know if you want a real answer for mark the question as solved

Comment: Yes I will validate your answer if you want to post one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentation take best practice both from [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) and [ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd) world.

The principle you are highlighting is about the presentation layer of the application that can use a **form component that can validate the user input** then this data is used for instantiate the Entity.

**In the example of the presentation the named constructor take as argument a form, so the validation of the email address is done by the form (validating user input).**

The meaning of having an object with a **valid state is intended about having an Object of type User that have both name, surname ad email  valid** (as example not null).

So you can have the following object:

```
class User
{

    private $name;

    private $surname;

    private $email;

    private function __construct(string $name, string $surname, string $email)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public static function create(string $name, string $surname, string $email): User
    {
        return new static($name, $surname, $email);
    }

    public function fromFormData(FormInterface $form):User
    {
        // The form validate user input (i.e. valid email address)
        return self::create($form->get('name'), $form->get('surname'), $form->get('email'));
    }

}
```

Another approach could be using DTO or you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/pugx/formable) useful bundle about validate DTOs object.

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

*Xero* inject the validator service in `__constructor` is not necessary (i.e. bad design IMHO) to validate your object. The constraints are validated on two possible events:

- On submit a form data and check `$form->isValid()` method [see doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#forms-form-validation)
- Directly by using a `validator` service [see doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

**Using the validator Service**

To actually validate an `Person` object, use the `validate` method on the `validator` service. The job of the validator is easy: to read the constraints (`@Assert`) of a class and verify if the data on the object satisfies those constraints. If validation fails, a non-empty list of errors is returned.

In your controller for exmaple:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($person);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $errorsString = (string) $errors;
}
```

Comment: yeah I get that. But if it's in the constructor, it's cleaner because the developer who used that later can forget to do this